# Problema al usar WhereEqualto en un Repo de recylcerView

Tags: firebase, kotlin, recyclerview, firestore

tengo una app en android Kotlin con una base de datos en Firebase, he creado un recyclerview que es alimentado con informacion extraida de Firestore, y para especificar la la coleccion donde estn almacenados los datos en la base de datos tengo el `RepoComent`. Cuando ejecuto el codigo los datos se cargan sin problema, el detalle viene cuando le agrego el `whereEqualTo` a la consulta directamente el recyclerview no es llenado con ningun tipo de informacion.

Este es mi `RepoComent`:

```
package com.ezdev.epetchepesapp.recycleComent

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import com.example.atipicoapp.recycleSlots.Anounce
import com.example.atipicoapp.recycleSlots.Coment
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query

class RepoComent {

    fun getComentData(pedidoId: String):LiveData<MutableList<Coment>>{

        println("Id-final: ${pedidoId}")

        val mutableData = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Coment>>()
        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Comentarios").whereEqualTo("idPubli", pedidoId).get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                mutableData.value = result.documents.map{ snap ->
                    snap.run{
                        Coment(
                            getString("user") ?: "default",
                            getString("contenido") ?: "1",
                            this.id ?: "1123",
                            getLong("time") ?: 1658715803
                        )
                    }
                }.toMutableList()
            }

        return mutableData
    }



}
```

No sé si el problema se ubica en el código del repo, o es error de las reglas de firebase...